# Camera Video not Working - React Native

Tags: ios, node.js, video, react-native, react-native-camera

## Question

I have been trying to figure out why this is not working for some time. I have used a lot of example code, however I still cannot figure it out.

## Code

```
 takeVideo() {
    console.log('started to take video');
    this.camera.capture({
      audio: true,
      mode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video,
      target: Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk
    }).then((data) => {
      this.setState({ path: data.path });
      console.log(data);
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  stopVideo() {
    this.camera.stopCapture();
    console.log(this.state.path);
  }

  renderCamera() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Camera
          ref={(cam) => {
            this.camera = cam;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
          captureTarget={Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk}
          captureMode={Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video}
        >
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.capture}
            onPressIn={this.takeVideo.bind(this)}
            onPressOut={this.stopVideo.bind(this)}
            underlayColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"
          >
            <View />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </Camera>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

#### Whats not working

When I `console.log(this.state.path)` it outputs `false` which means that it does not change and the video did not record.

## Info

- This is on IOS
- This **works** if I change `Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video` to `Camera.constants.CaptureMode.still` (`.video` => `.still`)
- RN version:
  `react-native-cli: 2.0.1`
  `react-native: 0.44.0`

## Repo

I found this repo that is trying to do almost the exact same thing as me and is having the same issue. Here is the repo: https://github.com/MiLeung/record

Comment: Did you fill in NSCameraUsageDescription in your info.plist?
Also, which lib for video are you using?

Comment: Yes, I have added that. Is there any way that the issue could be with the emulator?

Comment: Can you invoke these functions: https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera#component-static-methods let me know the outcomes, I've tried this repo today and everything worked fine in android. I'd like to help if I can

Comment: And also try this: `captureTarget= {Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.cameraRoll}`, where you define the camera in **render**

Comment: Thanks for the help! How should I run the functions you sent me? Should I run them before capturing the video? Also, here is the error that occurred after I changed the `captureTarget` to cameraRoll: http://imgur.com/a/SgJSS

Comment: @pudility sorry for late response, you can invoke the functions using ref to Camera component. Revert the captureTarget back to your version and invoke the functions again. Also keep in mind that there are few more captureTarget options

Comment: Yes, I have tried a number of things on a number of devices and emulators (Pixel, android nexus 5x emulator, iPhone 7, iPhone 6 plus, iPhone SE emulator, iPhone 6 emulator, iPhone 7 emulator, ect.).  All of them work with still but now video. Thanks for the help, but I think this might just be a bug.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @pudility  Please, try this one: https://github.com/ColCh/SO-4962215
It's working for me. Tested on XCode 8, react-native@0.44.0, iPhone 5C iOS 10.3.2. It's saves video as well as images. Screenshot of console with video recording: http://imgur.com/a/aHtCz . Does it throws something if you try to launch this project on real device?

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is, but when I run the exact same code as you it still doesn't work. http://imgur.com/a/tUEuq . Also, in my other post I made a typo I meant "but not video." not "but now video." Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your code is ok, however you're missing one important thing.

```
this.camera.capture({
      audio: true,
      mode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video,
      target: Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk
}).then((data) => {
      this.setState({ path: data.path });
      console.log(data);
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

In code above, you're telling state, to set object path **after** saving the data.

But, there:

```
stopVideo() {
    this.camera.stopCapture();
    console.log(this.state.path);
}
```

You're fetching path object **before** saving the data.

Just try this:

```
this.camera.capture({
          audio: true,
          mode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video,
          target: Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk
}).then((data) => {
          this.setState({ path: data.path });
          console.log(this.state.path); // You should have your path set
          console.log(data);
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

`stopCapture` function tells the native code, to stop recording and **save** video - what can take some time, so executing `this.state.path`  **immediately after** `stopCapture` does not work.

For more info check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise